# Query data nested within key

Tags: database, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, database-design

How do I query firebase for specific times?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to adopt another date format like `YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM` and your nodes will be sorted in a way you can use the [filtering methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data) (e.g. `startAt()`).

If you cannot change the key (it must stay like `11-20-2020 11:30` for any business or app architecture reason) you can add the `YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM` like value as a child node.